# Redis Database Connection Error in BullMQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis, bullmq

I'm trying to create a queue object and connect it to my Redis enterprise database. Below is the code:

```
import { Queue, FlowProducer } from "bullmq";
import env from "dotenv";

env.config()
const redisOptions = {
    username: 'Admin_user',
    password: `${process.env.REDIS_DB_PASS}`,
    host: 'redis-14244.c265.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
    port: 14244
}

export const my_Queue = {
    create_file_queue: new Queue("create-file", {connection: redisOptions}),
    construct_data_queue: new Queue("construct-data", {connection: redisOptions})
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

[ErrorReply: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair]

Node.js v18.14.1
```

Can anyone help with this??

I searched for sometime and ended up on this issue on GitHub [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but the solutions weren't very helpful

Comment: Please attach correct link to GitHUb

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to console.log `redisOptions` to confirm the values given are the values expected. Then, use those same credentials to manually connect to that instance of redis using the CLI or a gui like RedisInsight -- https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/